# how to SELECT from sql and use value within your code

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I am having a while loop where I loop the content of some posts. there is a summery of it and then the user can click "read more"

```
$list = '';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $summery = substr($row["content"], 0, 200); 
    $content = substr($row["content"], 200);
    $list .= '<section id="summery">'.$summery.'</section> <section id="content">'.$content.'</section>';
}
```

I want the user to be able to specify how long this summery should be in an input field. I don't want the user to get redirected to another page either when submit is clicked, so therefore I put the data from the input to the database and then I wanna retrieve it again in the while loop where I mention the amount of characters which in the example above is 200.

Something like this

```
$sql = "SELECT value FROM test";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);    

$list = '';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $summery = substr($row["content"], 0, $result); 
    $content = substr($row["content"], $result);
    $list .= '<section id="summery">'.$summery.'</section> <section id="content">'.$content.'</section>';
}
```

just cannot get it to work. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Okay, I think I see what you're doing. You need to fetch the data from your new query, the same way you did in the first example, then use resulting array to access `value`.

Comment: @JonStirling I have tried fetching like I do here, but how do I print the value within the while loop afterwards then?